# MongoClient.connect under Hyperledger Composer seems to throw error whilst trying to implement JWT authentication

Tags: node.js, docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

When I was following the [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/gangachris125/passport-jwt-authentication-for-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-jqfgkoljn), and trying to run `docker logs rest` it throws the below error: I dont seem to understand why

```
[2018-12-06 17:17:59] PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
[2018-12-06 17:17:59] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:composer-rest-server id:0
[2018-12-06 17:17:59] PM2 log: App name:composer-rest-server id:0 online
WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names.
WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
Discovering types from business network definition ...
(node:19) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
```

Expected Output:

```
docker logs rest
[2018-05-22 22:24:44] PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
[2018-05-22 22:24:44] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:composer-rest-server id:0
[2018-05-22 22:24:44] PM2 log: App name:composer-rest-server id:0 online
WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names.
WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
Discovering types from business network definition ...
Discovered types from business network definition
Generating schemas for all types in business network definition ...
Generated schemas for all types in business network definition
Adding schemas for all types to Loopback ...
Added schemas for all types to Loopback
Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
```

[Update]:

```
[2018-12-08 04:01:58] PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
[2018-12-08 04:01:58] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:composer-rest-server id:0
[2018-12-08 04:01:58] PM2 log: App name:composer-rest-server id:0 online
WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names.
WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
Discovering types from business network definition ...
```

Comment: The above only contains warnings and no error message, nothing to indicate an actual problem with the composer-rest-server. Please provide more details as to what the problem with the rest server is

Comment: @david_k Thank you for the message. I have added expected out. Because when I run `docker logs rest` it should start "explorer" at port 3000. However currently it seems to stop immediately after throwing that warning.

Comment: so a quick search on google suggests adding it to the options for mongo loopback so try

COMPOSER_DATASOURCES='{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "host": "mongo",
    "useNewUrlParser": "true"
  }
}'

Comment: Thanks @david_k It removed the error but still the network isnt working. I have added [update] if you knew how it can be solved.

Comment: But you can put this as a answer, I will mark it as a correc answer. Thanks.

Comment: So it looks like there are no error messages, does the container exit or is it still running and has just hung ? It's not possible to determine the cause from the output being produced I'm afraid.

Comment: Agreed. Is there any other test that you would like to try to determine the issue?

Comment: Sorry I'm out of ideas

Comment: Alright. Can you make this "so a quick search on google suggests adding it to the options for mongo loopback so try COMPOSER_DATASOURCES='{ "db": { "name": "db", "connector": "mongodb", "host": "mongo", "useNewUrlParser": "true" } }'" as a answer? such that I can mark it and close this question. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get rid of the warning message you need to add the option specified in the warning to the COMPOSER_DATASOURCES environment variable, for example

```
COMPOSER_DATASOURCES='{
   "db": {
     "name": "db", 
     "connector": "mongodb", 
     "host": "mongo", 
     "useNewUrlParser": "true"
   }
}'
```